# Browser doesn't display unicode properly

Tags: php, html, unicode, utf-8

This file is in UTF-8 already with:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

in the top but the word `CAFÉ` gets displayed as the following:

[image]

the HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title> form... </title>

</head>
<body>
CAFÉ
...
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You may have the metas set correctly, but is the file itself encoded in utf-8?

Comment: If the file is actually encoded in utf-8 and the charset is specifiedd as utf-8, then it leaves two options to explore : the server and the browser.

Comment: Is this from a database?

Comment: where from the text is coming .. from a database or hardcoded ?

Comment: Where should I start? I don't do much web development....

Comment: @AziBaloch: It comes from javascript, like: `document.getElementById("id").value = etc;`

Comment: can you show the full code ?

Comment: exactly like this except that I replaced the `café` word: 

`var f = [];
f.push('café');
document.getElementById("id").value = f.join('');
`

Answer (score 4):

The document is in fact interpreted as windows-1252 encoded. The UTF-8 form of [“É”](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c9/index.htm) consists of the two bytes 0xC3 0x89. Interpreted as windows-1252, they denote “Ã” and “‰”.

The most probable cause is that the *HTTP headers* sent by the server specify windows-1252 as the encoding (or iso-8859-1, which actually means the same thing). This information overrides any `meta` tags in the document itself.

Comment: Should I try change the encoding my server is using from Windows-1252 to UTF-8?

Comment: @Jack, I’d rather suggest using UTF-8 all the way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through